# Looking for concave-convex functions?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I need examples of 1-dimensional functions which are concave-convex, i.e. concave to the left and concave to the right of some point.

Examples would be $f(x)=x^3$ or $f(x)=\sin(x)$. I am looking for functions which are as flexible as possible, e.g. have some more parameters to adjust for the curvature.

Comment: Do you have any conditions on the regularity? If you want something smooth, do the following: In principle, if the point where it switches is say $x_0$, you might take a smooth function $f:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ which has a single zero in $x_0$ and which is negative for all $x<x_0$ and positive for all $x>x_0$. Then you integrate $f$ twice and you have what you are looking for.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be a convex function and $g(y)$ be a concave function (possibly $-f$). Then define
$$h(x) = f(\max\{x,0\}) + g(\min\{x,0\}) - f(0) - g(0)$$ Customize to your heart's content ;-)